# Call one WCF service application from another by making service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, service

I have one WCF service application (InstallerService) in which I have defined some methods. Now what I want to do is make a new WCF service application(say NewService) and call the methods of InstallerService from NewService. What I have already done is that I have made a service reference to InstallerService(Given the proper URL) and made client type object of this service reference in NewService.

I have also edited Web.Config for giving the endpoints etc. After doing all this while calling methods of InstallerService through NewService, I am getting the exception "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed."

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using REST for this.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb481074-ec8b-42d7-a4ed-24cb95287e14/the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-405-method-not-allowed?forum=wcf

Comment: InstallerService is hosted on internet. And your link says about publishing it through IIS. @PranayRana